# How to detect outgoing call number in Android Q

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm unable to get outgoing call number in **Android Q**.

I've registered receiver in the manifest with this intent filter `android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` and in code i'm detecting outgoing phone number like this

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"))
        String nr = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
}
```

But i can never get the outgoing call number in **Android Q**, is there a workaround to get this number differently or since **Android Q** it is completely impossible to detect outgoing call number?

Edit: It works with previous android versions

Answer (score 4):

You need to add PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS permission

**Create OutgoingCallReceiver**

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Service.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            if (tm.getCallState() == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {

                String number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

            }

    }

}
```

**Add required permissions to read outcomming call in AndroidManifest file**

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

**Request permissions at runtime**

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                    1);
        }
```

**Add OutgoingCallReceiver in AndroidManifest file**

```
  <receiver
        android:name=".application.services.OutgoingCallReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**This code will work fine with you, but** when you need to upload your application on Google play, It is ok with NEW_OUTGOING_CALL and READ_PHONE_STATE permission but,
you will receive a policy notice from playStore as:

Your app manifest requests the Call Log permission group (e.g. PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS)
It must be actively registered as the default Phone or Assistant handler on the device.

in this case you have 2 solution only if you want to read OutCommingCall Number:

Send declaration form to google [declaration form](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303)

Or Make your application dialer app

Check [Developer Policy Center](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/)

Comment: For me it works already. And I stumbled upon your answer while searching for something else and found something I was not aware of : many thanks for the headsup about the PlayStore policy!

Comment: Additionally there is no such `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` with `uses-permission` attribute. This is incorrect mention as a permission. Infact that has to be registered as an `intent-filter` inside the `Receiver` declaration, which is correctly pointed out. But OP asked about the deprecation of this `intent-filter`.

Comment: android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL is deprecated.

Comment: And also google play gonna reject your application if you use this permission

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for **android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL**:

> This constant was deprecated in API level 29. Apps that redirect
>   outgoing calls should use the CallRedirectionService API. Apps that
>   perform call screening should use the CallScreeningService API.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent

So I would implement this API first and check if it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

**Answered in Kotlin, not Java:**

**From sdk >=29** (Android 10 and up) you can register your app as a [CallRedirectionService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/CallRedirectionService), *"to interact between Telecom and its implementor for making outgoing call with optional redirection/cancellation purposes."*

This removes the need to create a custom [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver).

**1. On your AndroidManifest.xml file:**

```
<service
       android:name=".MyCallRedirectionService"
       android:exported="true"
       android:permission="android.permission.BIND_CALL_REDIRECTION_SERVICE">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.telecom.CallRedirectionService" />
       </intent-filter>
</service>
```

**2. Create `MyCallRedirectionService`:**

```
class MyCallRedirectionService : CallRedirectionService() {

    override fun onPlaceCall(
        handle: Uri,
        initialPhoneAccount: PhoneAccountHandle,
        allowInteractiveResponse: Boolean
    ) {

        // We can get the outgoing number from the handle parameter:
        Log.i("Phone Number:", handle.toString())
    }
}
```

**3. Use the [RoleManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/role/RoleManager) class to prompt the user to select your app as their CallRedirectionService:**

In this case, I'm requesting as soon as the app is created, over on the `MainActivity` `onCreate()` method:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        if (!isRedirection())
            roleAcquire(RoleManager.ROLE_CALL_REDIRECTION)
}
```

Here are the used functions:

```
    private fun isRedirection(): Boolean {
        return isRoleHeldByApp(RoleManager.ROLE_CALL_REDIRECTION)
    }

    private fun isRoleHeldByApp(roleName: String): Boolean {
        val roleManager: RoleManager? = getSystemService(RoleManager::class.java)
        return roleManager!!.isRoleHeld(roleName)

    }

    private fun roleAcquire(roleName: String) {
        val roleManager: RoleManager?
        if (roleAvailable(roleName)) {
            roleManager = getSystemService(RoleManager::class.java)
            val intent = roleManager.createRequestRoleIntent(roleName)
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Redirection call with role in not available",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }

    }

    private fun roleAvailable(roleName: String): Boolean {
        val roleManager: RoleManager? = getSystemService(RoleManager::class.java)
        return roleManager!!.isRoleAvailable(roleName)
    }
```